# Missing Maven Dependencies Library in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Something strange is happening in my eclipse.
Every thing was working great and suddenly after converting project to maven, Project cannot run main class.
As I see now, Maven Dependencies Library is not created after converting just the pom file and target folder. Moreover I am trying to add this library manually through build path and it does not work.

As someone told me, I run mvn clean : install and success run main class but this is not the great solution because when I , for example, add spring framework in the pox, it is not recognized. and any new project I need to run this command.

Furthermore project -> Properties -> Maven -> Missing Java EE integration

My Pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"   
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
       http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>training</groupId>
<artifactId>training</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.8</source>
      <target>1.8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

.project file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
<name>training</name>
<comment></comment>
<projects>
</projects>
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Builder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.m2e.core.maven2Nature</nature>
    <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
</natures>
</projectDescription>
```

.classpath file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<classpath>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java"/>
<classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="con"   

path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.    launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Thanks in advance,
Me

Comment: Does anything show up in Eclipse's Error Console?

Comment: How did you convert the project to maven? Has the project the Maven nature?

Comment: @Thevenin no error on Eclipce.

Comment: @hotzst By right click on the project ->Configure --> Convert to maven

Comment: could you try this, right click on project--> maven--> updateProject (select if there are any dependency project).

Comment: The solution was to open new workspace!